# Using req.body and a SELECT-statement simultaneously with Knex.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, api, knex.js

I am setting up a Node.js API with Knex.js, express.js and body-parser.

Now I want to do a Insert into, using at first

**request.body**  (I´m doing this with postman atm)

and on second Hand another insert into **using a select-statement** as shown below.

I already tried 2 knex.insert in a row, but it returns just the first one.
Do you think I should solve it just with a seperate ALTER TABLE statement when executing createQuestionnaire?

```
 table questionnaire
id,
title,         (insert using req.body)
description,   (insert using req.body)   
created_by_id (fk)  (insert using select-statement)


exports.createQuestionnaire = function (req, res) {

// The Code I need to implement

// knex('users').where({
//     id: req.session.passport.user
// }).select('id')

 //this works fine

knex
    .insert(req.body)
    .returning('*')
    .into('questionnaire')
    .then(function (data) {            
        res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: "Failed" }));
    });
};
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Why do you need the `id` from db if you have it already in the request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it and created multiple promises. When inserting, I used ES6 destructuring as shown in the Code

```
   let createdById = null;

   exports.createQuestionnaire = function (req, res) {
  //get id by user-login
   knex('users').where({
    id: req.session.passport.user
  }).select('id')
    //insert into questionnaire

    .then(function (user) {
        createdById = user[0].id;
        knex
            .insert({ ...req.body, created_by_id: createdById })
            .returning('*')
            .into('questionnaire')


            .then(function (data) {
       res.send(data) 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to execute query based on other query result you can chain multiple promises.

For example

```
exports.createQuestionnaire = function (req, res) {

knex('users').where({
    id: req.session.passport.user
}).select('id').then(rows => {

    if (!rows.length) {
        throw 'user-not-found'
    }

    req.body['created_by_id'] = rows[0].id;

    knex.insert(req.body) // Dangerous! You should check the required fields before inserting user input to db...
        .returning('*')
        .into('questionnaire')
        .then(function (data) {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: "Failed" }));
        });
});
```

}

P.S. Instead of using `then & catch` you can try with `async & await`, your code will be more readable.

Comment: exports.createQuestionnaire is a POST request, and you are combining now an INSERT with a seperate SELECT Statement within a post request?

Comment: Yes, of-course. The HTTP request methods the client use to interact with your server has nothing to do with the server or DB operations that need to be done to provide the requested results

Comment: Just to be sure that I´ve understood you : createQuestionnaire is used for an API-Endpoint  '/api/questionnaire/create' and its declared as  router.post('/create', passportJwt.authenticate('jwt', { session: true }), questionnaire.createQuestionnaire);    its legal to do any db-operation i want inside my function ?

Comment: What can make you think otherwise?

Comment: My lack of experience to be honest!  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your welcome, if my answer solved your problem please accept it as solution